# iptables help needed in 1304

Tags: networking, 13.04, firewall, iptables

I've setup my raring-ringtail machine and decided to use iptables after removing ufw to have more control over my network security. However, I'm stuck at one point. First, I've set default policy to deny all traffic by default:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

After that, I've added ACCEPT rules for my local network interfaces, which work fine. However, in order for some of my local services (such as web-server local browsing) to work, I need to allow traffic originating to/from my local interface  (lo). For this, I've found two versions on the net:

[1]

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT # Allow local addresses
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT # Allow local addresses
```

[2]

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT # Allow Allow local addresses
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT # Allow Allow local addresses
```

I want to know whats the difference between the two? Is allowing traffic to/from the "lo" interface same as originating/destined-to 127.0.0.1? Which one should I use and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interface `lo`.

1) Ubuntu/Debian weirdly use `127.0.1.1` instead of `127.0.0.1` to resolve your canonical hostname.

2) By default, 127.0.0.0/8 (127.anything) goes to the loopback. You shouldn't narrow your filters to only one of the addresses in that subnet.

> steven@lat:~$ ping 127.254.254.254 -c 1
>   PING 127.254.254.254 (127.254.254.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 127.254.254.254: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
>
> --- 127.254.254.254 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.052/0.052/0.052/0.000 ms
>   steven@lat:~$

3) You can assign any other addresses you like to the loopback adapter.

Whatever you do, `iptables -A INPUT -i lo -o lo -j ACCEPT` is not a bad idea. It says packets from this machine to this machine are acceptable.